# Xquery Replace Statement for multiple nodes

Tags: sql, replace, db2, xquery

This column (named docum_xml) in a DB2 Table has a xml structure like this:

```
    <member>
      <client1>
         <phone>510-000-0001</phone>
      </client1>
      <client2></client2>
      <client3>
         <phone>510-000-0002</phone>
      </client3>
      ...
    </member>
```

I want to do a xmlquery to get rid of all the potential dashes from  tag. The Query I wrote was:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET DOCUM_XML = XMLQUERY('
 TRANSFORM
 COPY $new := $documxml
 MODIFY(
 DO REPLACE VALUE OF $new//phone WITH fn:replace($documxml//phone,''-'',''''))
 RETURN $new' PASSING DOCUM_XML AS "documxml");
```

But it gave me error saying:
SQL16003N  An expression of data type "( item(), item()+ )" cannot be used when the data type "item()" is expected in the context.

I realized it errored out because I was trying to update multiple nodes, so I thought a for loop might be needed here. But I'm stuck in constructing the for loop and return the correct data back to my DB2 column. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!
Stella

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in the modify:

```
for $phone in $new//phone
return 
    replace value of node $phone
    with fn:replace($phone,''-'','''')
```

Comment: update TABLENAME
set DOCUM_XML = XMLQUERY('
transform
copy $new := $documxml
modify(
for $phone in $new//phone
return replace value of node $phone WITH fn:replace($phone,''-'','''')
)
return $new' PASSING DOCUM_XML AS "documxml");

Comment: I tried this one but it errored out due to syntax error. Where did I do it wrong?